# Why is there a "2" when deriving the OLS estimator in vector notation?

Tags: self-study, least-squares

My book says that the function to minimize is:

$S = e'e = (y - W\beta)'(y - W\beta) = y'y -y' W\beta -\beta' W'y + \beta ' W' W \beta$

and since they're all scalars:

$S =y'y -2\beta' W'y + \beta ' W' W\beta$

Then why, in the First order condition, it becomes the following?

$-2W'y + \underline{2} W'W\beta = 0$

Where does that 2 come from?

Comment: Hint: the derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$.

Comment: Also check (88) in matrix cookbook http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf